# Action method not being recognised when trying to insert data to database MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Action result method that is supposed to add data into a database when a button is clicked. Although, when I click on the button to add the data using the `AddDetails` Action method I get the following Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /home/AddDetails
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace //not included
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Details()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddDetails(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var db = new CustomerContext();
                db.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    ItemName = customer.ItemName,
                    Price = customer.Price
                });
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(customer);
        }


    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

    <h2>Add Items</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h2>Please type in Item Name and price paid</h2>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus />
            <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" required autofocus />


            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Add" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddDetails", "home")'" />
        </form>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're posting to /Customers/Details but your action is /Customers/AddDetails. You can tell your form to specifically post to /Customers/AddDetails or you can rename your AddDetails action to Details. It's fine to have both a GET and POST action called Details. When you issue a post request, the action with the HttpPost attribute will be hit. When you issue a get request, the action with no attribute or a HttpGet attribute will be hit.

If you want to keep the name 'AddDetails', your form should look like this (I'm using Razor instead of plain HTML):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post) {
    <h2>Please type in Item Name and price paid</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus />
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" min="0"  class="form-control" placeholder="Price" required autofocus />


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Add" />
}
```

Comment: Switch out your form with the (edited) one in my answer. I've never created a normal html form in asp.net mvc (only used the razor syntax) so I'm not sure if that's the problem. Now, nothing will map to the Customer arg in your AddDetails action but you at least shouldn't get the 404. Let me know if you aren't getting the 404 and I'll edit again so that you can actually post back a customer obj.

Comment: Ive tried this and it doesnt seem to do anything when clicking on the button to submit the data.

Comment: Sorry about that, try again. I had left type="button" and still added type="submit". That could have confused something. You only need the type="submit" (I edited my answer to reflect this.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I don't type fast enough...  As Neil mentioned, use the Html Helper, though I recommend using named parameters so that you don't confuse which is the Action and Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    actionName: "AddDetails", 
    controllerName: "Customer", 
    method: FormMethod.Post, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "myclass" }))
```

Also, to help keep the routes correct (and not need to rely on "magic strings"), I highly recommend using T4MVC.  Then your form will look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Customer.AddDetails(), ...)
```

And the Razor view will not even render if the Action does not exist.  It is also easier writing the form because Intellisense will help you find the Controller and Action you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make These changes in your code.

```
namespace //not included
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult AddDetails()
        {
           Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
            return View(newCustomer);
           //right click this action and choose addview and use strongly typed 
           //view by choosing Customer class
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddDetails(Customer customer)
        {
            //whatever you want here
        }


    }
}
```

You will get a view with all the syntax for form and input textBoxes. Just few minor additions to meet your UI requirement will be needed.

Feel free to ask more doubts if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Action name in `Html.BeginForm` like this `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post)`

**Or**

change you controller action name to `Details` instead of `AddDetails`